# Why does the direct image functor preserve softness of sheaves?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

Let $f: X \to Y$ be a continuous map and $\mathcal{F}$ a soft sheaf over $X$ (let's assume it is a sheaf of sets). I'm trying to prove that $f_{*} \mathcal{F}$ is also soft. (This is stated without proof in page 25 of Grauert's and Remmert's "Theory of Stein Spaces")

So, take the inclusion $i : Z \to Y$ of a closed set. Since $\mathcal{F}$ is soft, we have a global surjective map $\mathcal{F}(X) \to j_{*} j^{-1} \mathcal{F}(X)$, where $j: M \to X$ is also the inclusion of the corresponding closed set, $M = f^{-1}(Z)$. This induces another global surjection $f_{*}\mathcal{F}(Y) \to f_{*}j_{*}j^{-1}\mathcal{F}(Y)$.
Now, we also have
$$f_{*}j_{*}j^{-1}\mathcal{F} = (f \circ j)_{*} j^{-1} \mathcal{F} = (i \circ f|_{M})_{*} j^{-1} \mathcal{F} = i_{*} (f|_{M})_{*} \mathcal{F}|_{M}$$

I may be wrong, but I believe that we have a canonical iso $(f|_{M})_{*} \mathcal{F}|_{M} \cong (f_{*}\mathcal{F})|_{Z}$. And this would solve it since, then we would have that the canonical adjunction map $f_{*}\mathcal{F}(Y) \to i_{*} i^{-1} f_{*} \mathcal{F}(Y)$ would be surjective, which is what is intented. However, I can't seem to write the isomorphism and I keep getting confused with the sections, so it got very frustrating.

My question then is: Do we have the desired isomorphism? And if so, what is it explicitely?

or, more importantly

**Does this hold in full generality or do we need to impose some conditions on $X$, $Y$ or $f$**?

I would also be happy if a reference that fully approaches this question is provided.

Thank you for all the help in advance :)

Comment: You seem to be mistaking softness with flabbiness. We can take the sheaf of smooth functions on a smooth manifold and that is a soft sheaf which isn’t flabby

Comment: I'm not sure about the general case, but if $X$ is paracompact Hausdorff and $f$ is closed surjective continuous, we have for each closed subset $Z\subset Y$ an injective map $f_{*}\mathcal{F}(Z) \to \mathcal{F}(f^{-1}(Z))$ sending the class of a pair $(U,s)$ in $(f_{*}\mathcal{F})(Z)$ to the class of the pair $(f^{-1}(U),s)$ in $\mathcal{F}(f^{-1}(Z))$. This is because if $W$ is an open neighborhood of $f^{-1}(Z)$, there is an open neighborhood $G$ of $Z$ such that $f^{-1}(G)\subset W$.

Comment: Using surjectivity of $\mathcal{F}(X) \to \mathcal{F}(f^{-1}(Z))$ and injectivity of $f_*\mathcal{F}(Z) \to \mathcal{F}(f^{-1}(Z))$ we may deduce surjectivity of $f_*\mathcal{F}(Y) = \mathcal{F}(X) \to f_*\mathcal{F}(Z)$.

Comment: I saw this in Grauert's "Theory of Stein Spaces" and he didn't impose any conditions on the map or on the space. I also found that somewhat suspicious, but I don't know if it holds in full generality or not.